# Probability of $\lim \sup_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ of function sequence.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I might just be misunderstanding the notation here but I‘m supposed to show that for $(X_n)$ a sequence of i.i.d. uniformly distributed random variables on $[0,1]$ we have that:
$$
\lim \sup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\ln(n)}\ln(\frac{1}{X_n}) = 1
$$ almost surely.

For me this means that I need to show:
$$
\mathbb{P}(\{\omega \in \Omega : \lim \sup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\ln(n)}\ln(\frac{1}{X_n(\omega)}) = 1\}) = 1
$$

Where the $\lim \sup_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ is taken pointwise. I‘m supposed to show this using the Borel-Cantelli lemmas but these lemmas only allow me to make statements about the following probability:

$$ \mathbb{P}(\lim \sup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \{\omega \in \Omega : \frac{1}{\ln(n)}\ln(\frac{1}{X_n(\omega)}) = 1\}) = 1
$$

But these two sets aren’t equal, are they? Am I just understanding the exercise incorrectly and do I actually need to show the second statement or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Actually, $P(\{\omega \in \Omega : \frac{1}{\ln(n)}\ln(\frac{1}{X_n(\omega)}) = 1\})=P(X_n=\frac 1 n) = 0$ so you are not applying Borel Cantelli Lemma to the correct sequence of events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, let $Y_n$ be a sequence of independent random variables. The random variable $\limsup_{n\to\infty} Y_n$ is in the tail sigma algebra, which means it is always a constant random variable. In order to show that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} Y_n$ is equal to the constant $L$, you must show two things. For all $\newcommand{\e}{\varepsilon}\e>0$,

- $\mathbb P(Y_n>L+\e\;\text{ i.o})=0$,
- $\mathbb P(Y_n>L-\e\;\text{ i.o.})=1$.

Applying this to $Y_n:= \ln(1/X_n)/\ln(n)=-\ln X_n/\ln n$, this means you need to show that
$$
P\left(\frac{-\ln X_n}{\ln n}> 1\pm \e\;\text{ i.o.}\right)
$$
is either $0$ or $1$, depending on the $\pm$. Note
$$
P\left(\frac{-\ln X_n}{\ln n}>1\pm \e\right)=P(X_n < n^{-(1\pm \e)})=n^{-(1\pm \e)}
$$
Since the series $n^{-(1\pm \e)}$ is summable for $+$ and infinite for $-$, you can use the Borel-Cantelli lemmas to conclude that  $P\left(\frac{-\ln X_n}{\ln n}> 1\pm \e\;\text{ i.o.}\right)$ is $0$ for $+$ and is $1$ for $-$.

---

I see now what you were really asking about; you were confused about how the Borel-Cantelli lemmas deal with the lim sup of *events*, but you want to know how to apply that to the lim sup of *random variables*. Let my try to make this clear:

> **Lemma 1:** Let $Y_n$ be a sequence of random variables. Then
>
> $$\{\limsup Y_n \le L\}=\bigcap_{\e>0} (\limsup\{ Y_n> L+\e\})^c$$

This lemma connects the $\limsup$ of random variables to the complement of the $\limsup$ of certain events.

> *Proof:* If $\limsup Y_n\le L$, then by definition, for all $\e>0$, there exists $M\in \mathbb N$ so that $\sup_{n>M} Y_n \le L+\e$. On the other hand, if $\limsup \{Y_n> L+\e\}$ does not occur, then that means it is *not* true that for all $M\in \mathbb N$, there exists $n>M$ such that $Y_n >L+\e$. If you unpack these logical statements, you will find they are saying the exact same thing, so these are the same events.

Similarly, you can prove:

> **Lemma 2:** Let $Y_n$ be a sequence of random variables. Then
>
> $$\{\limsup Y_n \ge L\}=\bigcap_{\e>0} \limsup\{ Y_n> L-\e\}$$

This is the entire story of about how $\limsup$ of events relates to the $\limsup$ of events.  To connect this to the first part of my answer, recall that i.o. = infinitely often, which is the same as $\limsup$. That is,
$$
\{A_n\text{ i.o.}\}=\limsup A_n.
$$

Comment: Thank you, so formally I indeed need to show that:
$$ \mathbb{P}(\lim \sup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \{\omega \in \Omega : \frac{1}{\ln(n)}\ln(\frac{1}{X_n(\omega)}) = 1\}) = 1
$$ and not: $$
\mathbb{P}(\{\omega \in \Omega : \lim \sup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\ln(n)}\ln(\frac{1}{X_n(\omega)}) = 1\}) = 1
$$?